# Is it haram to hang duas, or an ayah, on the bathroom wall (i.e. in a picture frame)?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, sunnah

When entering restroom facilities, it is nice to be reminded of the many sunnahs that relate to using the bathroom, hygiene, etc. But is it haram to have a framed dua or Quranic verse hanging on the wall (in a picture frame)? Thank you in advance. Wasalaam.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you exactly mean by a 'hanging a prayer'?

Comment: I.e. a framed Arabic prayer

Comment: I guess that means "hanging a Qur'an verse in Arabic" or "hanging a dua in Arabic"; it doesn't make sense to "hang a prayer" (which is an *action* involving recitation, prostration, etc.).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I edited it. Sorry I was not clear. Let me know if I should edit it any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if one would learn the prayers (*duas*) by heart and practice the sunnah. Over time it will become second nature and you would need no external form of reminding.

Below is a Hadith that prohibited prayer (*salaat*) in a bathroom but the classification is Daif.

> It was narrated that Ibn 'Umar said: "Allah's Messenger prohibited
>   prayer from being performed in seven places: The garbage dump, the
>   slaughtering area, the graveyard, the commonly used road, the
>   ***bathroom***, in the area that camels rest at, and above the Ka'bah."
>
> [Sunan Ibn Majah 746](https://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/4/12)

Also as per Fathul Bari vol.1 [pg.197](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/15836); Daarul Qur’aan

> If a person forgets to read the Du’aa before entering the toilet, then
>   the Du’aa should be read in one’s heart, not on the tongue. However,
>   if the toilet and bathroom are combined, then before entering the
>   actual place of toilet, one may read the Du’aa verbally, on condition
>   one is not unclothed.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question "is it haram", I can only see how it answers "is it the most recommended course of action".

Comment: @G.Bach honestly you are correct. I accepted the answer because Ahmed put alot of effort into it. Perhaps that was not the wisest decision. Ahmed, would you be able to confirm this as halal or haram? Jazak.

Comment: Hanging ayahs or duas on the walls in general is contrary to the practice of the Prophet (SAW) and the Khulafaa’ al-Raashidin (RA), who never did such a thing. The best way is to follow them and not to introduce bid‘ah. Since it was never a practice there are not many Hadiths that talk on the subject directly. You can further deduce the ijtehad on the practice w.r.t washroom. Please also visit this link which has a response by Sheikh Muhammed Salih Al-Munajjid : https://islamqa.info/en/254 ... And Allah knows best and we pray to Him to guide us to the straight path. Ameen.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. I’m assuming this does not apply to the masaajid, as they are commonly decorated internally with duas and verses. Wasalaam.

Comment: The moderators on this forum advise us against asking multiple questions in a single query  and also tend to move comments to the chat section at times. Hence, I'd advice you to post that as a separate question to help other members too :)

Comment: @Ahmed my question asks about bathroom walls specifically. Your comment above refers to walls in general, which shifts the conversation.

Comment: @Ahmed "Hanging ayahs or duas on the walls in general is contrary to the practice of the Prophet (SAW) and the Khulafaa’ al-Raashidin (RA), who never did such a thing." So is driving a car, or drinking chai latte. That doesn't show it's haram.

Comment: @G. Bach In Islam, bidah refers to innovation in religious matters.

Comment: @Ahmed Your answer says nothing about bidah; if your answer is "it's haram because it's bidah", your answer should reflect that.

Comment: @G.Bach One cannot label a practice that was non-existent at the Prophet's time as either Halal or Haram if not alluded to by the Quran or the Prophet. The ulema through ijtehad will classify such practices as either mustahab, mubah or makruh.

Comment: @G.Bach In my answer, I have provided references that state that it is mustahab (recommended) to read the duas before entering the toilet.Also in my earlier comment I have provided a link that refers to a fatwa by Shiekh AL-Munajid w.r.t hanging quranic verses on walls in general. It can be deduced that if it is considered makruh to hang these in a normal place of stay like the bedroom or hall which are considered clean and pure, then it would be more disliked to the same in a toilet which are relatively unclean and impure.

Comment: @G.Bach If you have a different opinion, please do feel free to enlighten us. We all learn through sharing on this forum. :-)